# Why is this div element ignoring my z-index and width settings?

Tags: html, css

I tried to use HTML+CSS to generate simple inline info popups, yet I was not able to make it work as intended. In particular, the popup div container ignores my *max-width* and *z-index* settings.

I posted [a small demonstration on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMh8j/2/).

Can someone please enlighten me? What am I missing? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @SACHIN: Please look at the jsfiddle linked in the question. When you hover your mouse above the [?] symbol, a text box pops up. This box, however, should be stacked below the div that contains [?] (already solved below), and it should also respect given min-width and max-width setting, which it currently doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set positions to absolute/relative/fixed in order for z-index to work http://jsfiddle.net/NMh8j/12/

Answer (score 1):

If you change `.faq>.body` to `position:fixed`, the 240px width is observed, and the `top : 12px` is moving the popup over the underlying ?. You can then drop the `left-20px` as well as it will center itself.

[jsFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/NMh8j/13/)

Comment: Yes, but this positions the popup relative to the window and not to the [?] sign, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.head` hasn't any position specified, change your CSS to :

```
.faq:hover>.head { 
   position: relative;
   border-color:#cccccc; 
   border-bottom-color:#ff0000; 
   z-index:100;
}
```

`z-index` need the `position` property to be fixed (`fixed`, `absolute`, `relative`.. but **not** `static`, which is the default value)